# Swapping dynamic elements with identical ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

This is a bit tricky so I hope I can explain it clearly:

I have a glossary script that loads xml dynamically into a container. The elements are generated on the page from the xml, with set ids. My client wants to create a tabbed structure on the page where each tab content contains one of these glossaries. Is there a way to safely do this, perhaps by removing the tab content field from DOM and switching it out for a structurally identical one when a new tab is clicked? Was also thinking iframe but that seems awful... Is there a better method and how would I extend the "init" function to use it? Here's the content of the HTML body, thus far:

```
<script src="{{root}}assets/js/glossary.js"></script>

<section id="content" class="large-collapse">

    <ul class="tabs" data-tabs id="taxonomies">
        <li class="tabs-title is-active"><a href="#panel1" aria-selected="true">Cleanser</a></li>
        <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel2">Toner</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="taxonomies">

        <div class="tabs-panel is-active" id="panel1">

            <!-- dynamic container -->
            <div id="glossary-container"></div>

        </div>

        <div class="tabs-" id="panel2">

            <!-- dynamic container -->
            <div id="glossary-container"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>

    <script>
    var glossary;

    function init() {

    //create the screen object which loads the xml and creates all screen elements
    glossary = new Screen({
    id: "ingredientsGlossary",
    xmlPath: "{{root}}assets/xml/cleanser.xml"
    });

    //choose a target div
    var targetDiv = get("glossary-container");

    //load it
        glossary.load(targetDiv, false);
    }
    //kick off
    window.onload = function() {
        init();
    };
    </script>
```

Thanks for any insight for a beginner.

Comment: is this not possible?

Comment: Can't you transform the XML into HTML that will be valid -- that is, by removing the id's that would be duplicated?

Comment: Well the XML is being transformed into dynamic HTML by the plugin script then attached to the container by the above function. Thanks.

Comment: If you've got, or can add, jQuery, you could add this right before "//load it" : targetDiv.removeAttr( "id");